# How to combine files with unix cat command based on file name, then rename?

Tags: unix, unix-shell, command-line-interface, cat

I have a bunch of CSV files in a directory like:

modfinalak_1.csv
modfinalal_1.csv
modfinalal_2.csv
modfinalal_3.csv
modfinalar_1.csv
modfinalar_2.csv

so it's one or multiple files per each US state (AK, AL, AR, etc.).  How can I use cat to combine all the files for each state and then rename the file to the state name?

In the above example, I want modfinal_1.csv,modfinalal_2.csv,and modfinalal_3.csv to be combined and renamed to al.csv.  How do you get cat to do this based on the text before the '_' character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would do it in bash (list all the state abbreviations in the list between `in` and `;`):

```
 for s in ak al ar ; do cat *${s}_*.csv > $s.csv ; done
```

If you have the state abbreviations in a file `states.txt`, the line could look like this:

```
 for s in `cat states.txt` ; do cat *${s}_*.csv > $s.csv ; done
```